# Depth of Schubert cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, intersection-theory, schubert-calculus

For $a:a_1\geq \cdots\geq a_c$, let $\sigma_a$ be the corresponding Schubert cycle over $Gr(c,\infty)$. We say $a$ is of depth $k$ if $a_1-a_c=k$ ($c>1$). Let $a$ and $b$ be of depth $k_1$ and $k_2$, respectively. Is the following true?

Among all Schubert cycles inside the expansion of $\sigma_a\cdot \sigma_b$, there is one whose depth is at most $\max(k_1,k_2)$.

One need to use Littlewood-Richardson rule cleverly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let $(d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_c)$ be the partition obtained by sorting $(a_1+b_c, a_2+ b_{c-1}, \cdots, a_c+b_1)$ into decreasing order. The Parthasarathy-Ranga Rao-Varadarajan conjecture, now proved by [Kumar](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=943925) (see also [Knutson and Tao](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9807160)), has as a special case that $\sigma_d$ has nonzero coefficient in $\sigma_a \cdot \sigma_b$.

Now, the depth of $d$ is
$$\max_{1 \leq i,j \leq c} (a_i+b_{c+1-i}) - (a_j + b_{c+1-j}).$$
Whenever $i<j$, we have
$$(a_i+b_{c+1-i}) - (a_j + b_{c+1-j}) = (a_i - a_j) - (b_{c+1-j} - b_{c+1-i}) \leq a_i - a_j \leq k_a.$$
Similarly, whenever $i > j$, we have 
$$(a_i+b_{c+1-i}) - (a_j + b_{c+1-j}) \leq k_b.$$

By the way, the PRV conjecture can be used to give an alternate proof of the result you asked about [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154537/upper-bound-for-the-product-of-schubert-cycles), that the smallest possible value for $d_1$ is $\max(a_1+b_c, a_2+b_{c-1}, \ldots, a_c+b_1)$.